# Basic Material Issue

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm new to Blender. I tried following a few tutorials to apply, scale, project/wrap textures etc. My texture is looking correct in the material preview but not in the render mode. Are my nodes incorrect?[image]

Comment: Hello Sara :). When texture isn't displayed on a model (there's only a solid color), it often due to a missing UV map. Have you UV unwrapped your model?

Comment: If you want info on UV mapping, check out this guide, It might seem a bit intimating because it is rather in-depth, but I've always recommended it, as it is very thorough. - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/